# Mark up tool for Notes in macOS

Tags: macos, notes.app, markup

Is there a way to use the mark up tool in notes? Or something that works like that would? I want to be able to put shapes with text on top of copy pasted images. So I want to use a shape, be able to type text on the shape then put it on top of a image.

Answer (score 2):

With the image inserted in Notes, choose the disclosure arrow from the top-right of the image (shown on hover) and select Markup.

[image]

From here you have access to the standard markup tools including shapes and text.

[image]

Comment: @user [That's an extension provided by Pixelmator.](http://www.pixelmator.com/retouch-extension/)